# Update statement not changing anything after commit C#

Tags: c#, sql-update, tableadapter

What I am trying to do is get some user's data, show it to him and if he/she wants she can change some of the values and then commit changes at button click. I am using table adaptes and in the one which is used here I have generated an `UpdateQuery` which takes only few of the db's columns and the ID as something to refer the line to.

At page load I am fetching data from the DB to populate the textboxes with information. Then at button click I am assigning the textboxes' values to local variables and trying to update the DB with them. The code runs trough the `UpdateQuery()` without catching any exceptions, but is not changing anything.

If I run the query from the `Query builder` while generating the `UpdateQuery` everything goes smooth and changes are made. What am I missing ? Here is the code behind this explanation:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserDetailsTableAdapters.UserDetailsTableAdapter userDetails = new UserDetailsTableAdapters.UserDetailsTableAdapter();
        UserDetails.UserDetailsDataTable loginDetailsTable = userDetails.GetData(); 

        foreach (DataRow row in loginDetailsTable.Rows)
        { 
            Int32 id = System.Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["UserInformation"]["ID"]);
            if (id == System.Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"])) 
            {
                txt_email.Text = System.Convert.ToString(row["email"]);
                txt_address.Text = System.Convert.ToString(row["address"]);
                txt_number.Text = System.Convert.ToString(row["mobileNum"]);
                txt_firstName.Text = System.Convert.ToString(row["firstName"]);
                txt_lastName.Text = System.Convert.ToString(row["lastName"]);
            }
        }
        lbl_info.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["UserInformation"]["ID"]);//this is here to check that the right cookie ID is passed.
    }
    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserDetailsTableAdapters.UserDetailsTableAdapter userDetails = new UserDetailsTableAdapters.UserDetailsTableAdapter();
        UserDetails.UserDetailsDataTable loginDetailsTable = userDetails.GetData(); 

        string email = txt_email.Text;
        string address = txt_address.Text;
        string number = txt_number.Text;
        string firstName = txt_firstName.Text;
        string lastName = txt_lastName.Text;

        foreach (DataRow row in loginDetailsTable.Rows)
        { 
            Int32 id = System.Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["UserInformation"]["ID"]);
            if (id == System.Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"])) 
            {
                try
                {
                    userDetails.UpdateQuery(email, address, number, firstName, lastName, id);
                    //Response.Redirect("MyProfile.aspx");
                }
                catch (Exception Exception)
                {
                    btn_submit.Text = Exception.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: My custom `UpdateQuery` looks like this:

```
UPDATE UserDetails
SET    email = ?, address = ?, mobileNum = ?, firstName = ?, lastName = ?
WHERE  (ID = ?)
```

It is done through the tableAdapter's Query Builder and runs perfectly well when executed in the Query Configuration Wizard. The `UpdateQuery` method expects 6 elements: `email, address, mobileNum, firstName, lastName` and `ID`

Comment: `userDetails` has no `Commit` or `AcceptChanges` methods. I have very limited choice of methods available to use, none of which seems to be dealing with any further updating after the `Update` call.

Comment: it's hard to determine what `userDetails` has since we do not know if this is something custom that you have created or if it's native to `TableAdapter` what does a google search yield when you do it for `TableAdapter.Update`

Comment: question's edited. I am not using a simple Update statement as I want to change specific, not all of the columns. This made me do a custom Update query

Comment: I understand how to use it I've used it before.. but I am wondering if at design time something is not being overwritten during runtime.. I had this issue once before too but I went away from using TableAdapters and started using SqlClient data objects instead.. was much easier to code and debug in regards to creating stored procedure and update / insert / select query's